# "javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component" for <p:growl> component?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I have the following Facelets code with an update on the `<p:growl>` component after the saving action.
But I have the following exception while rendering the page :

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with expression ":principal:display" referenced from "mainForm:form1:j_idt27".

```
<ui:define id="principal" name="content">
    <p:growl id="display" showDetail="true" sticky="false" />

    <p:panel header="Gestion de projets">

        <h:form id="form1">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputText value="Nom du projet: *" />
                <p:inputText value="#{gestionProjetBean.nomProjet}"
                    required="true" label="Nom du projet" />
                <p:commandButton value="Save"
                    actionListener="#{gestionProjetBean.creerProjet(gestionProjetBean.nomProjet)}"
                    update=":principal:display" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: It can't find the selector for it,  look at your xhtml output to find the direct id - try just doing update="display"

Comment: @BalusC I've seen that post before posting my question and it helped me undertanding the findComponent mechanism but it doesn't helped me to find the solution for my problem, since I wasn't able to find the real id of my component.

Comment: Just do rightclick and *View Source* in browser?

Comment: yes it displayed me all the components and their id in simple html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution: **it should be `update=":mainForm:display"`**

For those who are facing the same problem, **firebug** helped me finding the real id of the component, by displaying the source code of the page and searching for my component on it.

There, I found this:

`<div id="mainForm:msgs" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite"></div>
<span id="mainForm:display"></span>
<script id="mainForm:display_s" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Growl','widget_mainForm_display',{id:'mainForm:display',sticky:false,life:6000,escape:true,msgs:[]});});
</script>`

Also don't forget to prepend the id by an "**:**" (because every id should start with the NamingContainer separator character ":")

Comment: It's illegal to nest forms. The other answer didn't expect that you were doing that.

Comment: Ohhh thank you @BalusC, I totally forgot that I was using a template `<p:layoutUnit styleClass="layoutUnitCenter" position="center">
<h:form id="mainForm">
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" id="msgs" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" />
<ui:insert name="content" />
</h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>`.

Ok that's where the mainForm id came from... Thank you very much, I though that it was a  hidden component in primefaces... It's more clear now. but the solution still valid.

Answer (score 0):

don't use :principal:display try just :display

Comment: already tried and it doesn't work

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work". any error or just no functionality ?

Comment: I mean the same exception has been raised

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
  give a id to the panel component and modify code like below

```
:panelid:display
```

this works for me.

Comment: this wouldn't work since the <p:growl> which id is "display" is outside the panel. But, anyway, I tried and (as expected) it doesn't work and throwed the same exception